# Unknown column '..' in 'field list' join

Tags: mysql, delimiter, outer-join

I made a simple query with join but get always this annoying error. 
The query:

```
SELECT 
    `verk.id`, `verk.date`, `verk.quant`, `verk.verid`, `verk.kunde`, `verk.gebracht`, `loginuser_aqa.name`, `loginuser_aqa.id`
FROM 
    `verk` 
FULL JOIN 
    `loginuser_aqa`
ON
    loginuser_aqa.id = verk.verid
WHERE
    verk.gebracht = 0
ORDER BY  verk.date;
```

The error:

> **Unknown column 'verk.id' in 'field list'**

Provided a demo on rextester:
http://rextester.com/HDTJAA39589
I already tried to leave "`verk`" from `verk.id` away, but then i get another error:

> id is ambiguous..

Comment: Did you know that you don't normally need to type a single backtick in your SQL code?

Comment: @Álvaro González thanks for telling it, normally i use it always in the select clause. ;D From now i will leave them ;D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least two problems in this query.

First, when you use back-ticks to delimit identifiers, you must delimit the table alias separately from the column name.

```
`verk.id`   -- WRONG

`verk`.`id` -- CORRECT
```

The reason is that SQL actually allows you to define column names containing punctuation, white space, etc. if you delimit the column names. So that's what you appear to be doing, requesting a column named `verk.id`

```
verk.id     -- ALSO CORRECT
```

As others have commented, you don't usually need to use delimited identifiers at all. Use them if your identifiers conflict with [MySQL Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), or if you need to use punctuation, whitespace, or international characters.

The second problem is the MySQL doesn't support `FULL JOIN`. It doesn't even recognize `FULL` as an SQL keyword. So your query formed like this:

```
...
FROM 
    `verk` 
FULL JOIN 
    `loginuser_aqa`
ON ...
```

Is interpreted by MySQL as if you had done this:

```
...
FROM 
    `verk` AS `FULL`
JOIN 
    `loginuser_aqa`
ON ...
```

In other words, since `AS` is an optional keyword in SQL, you have just set `FULL` as the table alias for `verk`.

When you define a table alias, you *must* use the table alias for any column belonging to that table. You can no longer reference columns as `verk.id`, you must use `FULL.id`. This part is standard SQL behavior, not a MySQL bug.

Another problem with this is that you aren't getting a `FULL OUTER JOIN` in your query result, you're just getting a plain `JOIN` which is a synonym for `INNER JOIN`. There's no error, but if you needed a full outer join, you won't get the results you expect.

I reported the issue of MySQL not supporting `FULL` as a reserved word in 2013: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69858 You can add your vote to the priority of the bug if you want by logging in and clicking the "Affects me" button on that page.

If you need to do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` in MySQL, you must use a workaround. See example here: [Full Outer Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Comment: I'm glad to help. Remember that it is customary on Stack Overflow to upvote and/or accept an answer that helps you.

Comment: Yeah i had to wait 10 minutes or similar after post my question ;D.

Answer (score 2):

You enclosing the whole thing in backticks.

Instead of:

```
`table.col`
```

use

```
`table`.`col`
```

Also, MySQL doesn't have `FULL JOIN`. Please check what you want to achieve using FULL JOIN. There are techniques present to emulate it.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    v.`id`, v.`date`, v.`quant`, v.`verid`, v.`kunde`, v.`gebracht`, a.`name`, a.`id`
FROM 
    `verk` v
LEFT JOIN 
    `loginuser_aqa` a
ON
    a.`id` = v.`verid`
WHERE
    v.`gebracht` = 0
ORDER BY  v.`date`;
```

Comment: It lstill not working? Or the demo site is bugging. http://rextester.com/WRDDB61441